# If statement in (Objective-)C

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, if-statement

I want to check different variables BUT if only just one meets the condition required then I get an alert view. I tried with `if( && )` but it didn't work the way I want it. I think what I am looking for is something like an "or" statement.

```
if(_d0 == 0 && _d1 == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Input Error"
                                                    message: @"Need to Choose Sections"
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

So I want it to check if _d0 = 0 or _d1 == 0 , even if one of these two is 0 i need the alert view to pop. The thing is that If i do separated statements, then if the user doesn't choose any of the two sections,it will pop two alert views, which will be annoying cause in some cases the user needs to choose 5 different sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you want exactly

```
if ((_d0 == 0) || (_d1 == 0))
{
    // popup alert view
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I was looking for but didn't know how to look for it!

Comment: @user1536112 protip: you can google things like this as `C programming logical OR operator`

Comment: I had to wait for marking as correct answer and i cant upvote unfortunately with my reputation. thank you again very much once again.

Comment: @user1536112 you may want to bookmark the following page, it's a breakdown of all objective-c operators. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/objectivec-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is *and*. You want to use `||` for *or*